# How to iterate from multidimention json array

Tags: jquery, json

How do I iterate through a JSON return via jQuery and return the index of each object?

Examples of some of my code below:

```
 foreach ( x = somevalue  ; x < length of array ; x +++
{
            that x must be the index 
         [0] => Array

          $('#actual_'+x).text(data.actual+" hrs.");
          $('#total_'+x).text(data.total+" hrs.");
          $('#regular_'+x).text(data.regular+" hrs.");



}

  (
[0] => Array
    (
        [actual] => 9
        [total] => 10
        [regular] => 0
        [over] => 11
        [total_h] => 11
        [eng_pay] => 148.5
        [rate] => 9
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [actual] => -1
        [total] => 0
        [regular] => -1
        [over] => 2
        [total_h] => 1
        [eng_pay] => 18
        [rate] => 9
    )
```

)

I would like to iterate through this jQuery ajax widget's success function:

```
  $.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url: 'cal_grid.php',
  dataType: 'json',
     cache: false,

      data:$('#grid_frm').serialize(),
      success: function(data) 


      {


        alert(data);



      }  // response call back ends

    });//ajax call ends
```

Comment: `var x; for (x = 0; x < data.length; x++) { /* Your jQ code */ }` - although I have to say this question is so badly formatted as be pretty much incomprehensible so whether that helps you at all is anybodies guess. Imagine you were trying to answer this question - would you understand the random mix of Javascript, pseudo code and PHP `print_r()` output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

untested, but should do the trick. throw this into your success function.

```
$.each($(data), function(i, obj){
   console.log(i); //spits out your index into console
});
```